# How to add/update approvers for environments through REST API on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]

I am trying to make hundreds of environments on Azure Devops using a PowerShell script and REST API. I need to include approvers on some of it.
I can already create those environments, I just need to add/update the approvers for it.
How can I do that? I can't seem to find anything on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add /update the approvers for environments, you can use the following Rest API:

Add approvers for environment:

**Rest API:**

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/Orgname/Project/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations?api-version=api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "type":{
        "id":"8C6F20A7-A545-4486-9777-F762FAFE0D4D",
        "name":"Approval"
    },
    "settings":{
         "approvers":[{"displayName":"{UserName}","id":"{UserID}"}],
         "executionOrder":1,
         "blockedApprovers":[],
         "minRequiredApprovers":0,
         "requesterCannotBeApprover":false
    },
     "resource":
         {
             "type":"environment",
             "id":"{EnvironmentID}",
             "name":"{EnvironmentName}"
         }
}
```

Update approvers for environment:

**Rest API:**

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations/{Configurationid}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "type":{
        "id":"8C6F20A7-A545-4486-9777-F762FAFE0D4D",
        "name":"Approval"
    },
    "settings":{
         "approvers":[
             {
             "displayName":"{Username}",
             "id":"{UserID}"
             },
             {
             "displayName":"{Username}",
             "id":"{UserID}"
             }
             ],
         "executionOrder":1,
         "blockedApprovers":[],
         "minRequiredApprovers":0,
         "requesterCannotBeApprover":false
    },
     "resource":
         {
             "type":"environment",
             "id":"{EnvironmentID}",
             "name":"{EnvironmentName}"
         }

}
```

For the configuartionID, you can get the ID in the following Rest API: [Check Configurations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/check-configurations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

Since the requirement has no official sample, you can check the NetWork trace for more detailed info.

For example: Manually add/update the approvers and Check network tab in Browser Developer tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Approvals and Checks API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)